# Need some help creating a fading image effect with one image and jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade

Im trying to create a fade effect between "two" images just using one image in two containers and shifting the background postion. Below is the following HTML markup I'm working with.

```
<div class="project">
    <a href="b-portfolio-detail.php?project=52"><img src="../projects/life4wrd.jpg" alt="Life4wrd" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="b-portfolio-detail.php?project=53" class="cover" style="background-position:0 -302px;">Life4wrd</a>
</div><!--/project-->
```

And here is the little jQuery I have.

```
$('.project img').attr('src');
```

There are multiple div.project contains, each with their own thumbnail. What I would like to do for each project div is to get the src from the img in the first anchor link and set that as a background for the second anchor link, (the one with the class called "cover") and also set the background position on the div.cover to 0px -302px.

I understand how to get the img src attribute but Im not sure how to get it for each div.project and also how to pass it back in a the background image for .cover.

Comment: what about .fadeIn() on the back image and .fadeIn() on the front image? You can do the two asynchronously I think, and the final effect is a transition between two images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.project .cover').css({display:'none',backgroundPosition:'0 -302px'}).attr('src',$('.project img').attr('src')).fadeIn();
$('.project img').fadeOut();
```

something like this?

Comment: Not quite, but I tweaked my mark-up tow work with your code.  Im now using this for my HTML:
<div class="project">
<a href="b-portfolio-detail.php?project=52"><img src="../projects/life4wrd.jpg" alt="Life4wrd" border="0" /></a>
<a href="b-portfolio-detail.php?project=50" class="cover-box"><img src="" class="cover"></a>
                   
</div><!--/project-->

But thanks for the quick reply, the effect is now exactly what I was going for!